# Performance issues when parsing nested multi-row structures within Oracle DB field

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help on performance for a query to parse data from a multi-row structure that is nested within a cell. My SQL is working but is very slow and won't scale sufficiently well. It's stored in an Oracle database for the application Aurion HR.

**n.b. I don't have permission to run the query optimiser or to create tables. I have requested this but turnaround on getting this access may be slow**

The structure of the data is:

- 1. The table T526_TIME_ENTRY_HEADER has one row for each pay period the employee worked (e.g. a 2 week period)
  2. Within this table, the field T526F900_DATA is of type BLOB and contains data delimited by a combination of CHR(21) (NAK) and CHR(27) (ESC) characters.
  3. Within the nested structure in T526F900_DATA, each time sheet entry (e.g. 6-11am on 1-Jan) is separated by 2 x CHR(21) followed by 1 x CHR(27)
  4. Within each time sheet entry, the fields (e.g. start time, end time, break hours etc) are separated by 3 x CHR(21) followed by 1 x CHR(27)

I want to be able to filter and then keep some attributes from the original TIME_HEADER table (e.g. employee number), and then link it to the individual timesheet fields at the lowest level. The code I'm currently using to do this is shown below (slightly redacted).

**Is there anything obvious about the structure or steps taken that could be changed to improve performance?** I'll endeavour to provide more information if requested.

The SQL here works, but takes about 40 minutes to run for 1 year of data on a subset of org units, and I'd like to run it for 4+ years on all org units.

```
/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- isolate nested field and convert weird delimiters to comma field delimiter and pipe record delimiter
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
WITH Delimited_Data AS
(
    SELECT
        T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO,
        T526F010_TRANS_NO,
        regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(T526F900_DATA,CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27),','), -- first replace regular delimiters with comma
            CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), -- then replace end of record/line with pipe
            '|'
        ) AS T526F900_DATA_Delimited
    FROM T526_TIME_ENTRY_HEADER T526
    INNER JOIN T104_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY T104     -- link to placements to get org unit
        ON T104.T104F005_EMPLOYEE_NO = T526.T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO
        AND T526.T526F020_PERIOD_FROM BETWEEN T104F025_DATE_EFFECTIVE AND T104F030_DATE_TO
    WHERE 1=1
        AND T526F020_PERIOD_FROM >= '01/JAN/22'
        AND T104F045_ORGANISATION_UNIT_NO BETWEEN 180 AND 189 -- selected org units
    ORDER BY T526F020_PERIOD_FROM
),

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- split each timesheet entry onto a new row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Pivoted_Data AS (
    SELECT
        T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO,
        T526F010_TRANS_NO,
        trim(regexp_substr(
            REPLACE(T526F900_DATA_Delimited, 'ENTRY_LINES=SECTION1=',''),
            '[^\|]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as DATA_ 
    FROM Delimited_Data,
      table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(T526F900_DATA_Delimited, '[^\|]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels 
),

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- parse key fields from each timesheet row like date, start and end time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Extracted_Data AS (
    SELECT
            regexp_substr(DATA_,'N026F025_DATE=\.*(.*?)\.*,.*', 1, 1, NULL, 1) N026F025_DATE, -- find the string of 'N026F025_DATE' field
            regexp_substr(DATA_,'N026F030_TIME_FROM=\.*(.*?)\.*,.*', 1, 1, NULL, 1) N026F030_TIME_FROM,
            regexp_substr(DATA_,'N026F050_TIME_TO=\.*(.*?)\.*,.*', 1, 1, NULL, 1) N026F050_TIME_TO, -- find the string of 'time_to' field
            regexp_substr(DATA_,'N026F020_TIME_TYPE=\.*(.*?)\.*,.*', 1, 1, NULL, 1) N026F020_TIME_TYPE,
            T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO,
            T526F010_TRANS_NO
    FROM Pivoted_Data
    WHERE
        SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(DATA_),1,4) = 'N026' -- Only include timesheet entry rows with a Time to/from (they start with N026)
)

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Link to employee and placement details
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SELECT
    T001F010_WAMI_KEY,
    T001F005_EMPLOYEE_NO,
    T000F020_GIVEN_NAMES,
    T000F015_SURNAME,
    T104F025_DATE_EFFECTIVE,
    T104F030_DATE_TO,
    T104F115_TITLE,
    T104F085_EMPLOYMENT_TYPE,
    T104F045_ORGANISATION_UNIT_NO,
    TO_DATE(N026F025_DATE,'YYYYMMDD') N026F025_DATE_DT,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(N026F025_DATE,'YYYYMMDD'), 'DY') AS N026F025_DATE_DayName,
    TO_NUMBER(N026F030_TIME_FROM) AS N026F030_TIME_FROM,
    TO_NUMBER(N026F050_TIME_TO) AS N026F050_TIME_TO,
    N026F020_TIME_TYPE,
    (CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(N026F030_TIME_FROM) < 6000000  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StartBefore6AM,
    (CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(N026F050_TIME_TO) > 18000000 AND TO_NUMBER(N026F050_TIME_TO) < 24000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Finish6PMto12AM,
    (CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(N026F050_TIME_TO) > 00000000 AND TO_NUMBER(N026F050_TIME_TO) <= 08000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Finish12AMto8AM
FROM
    T001_BASIC_DETAILS T001
    INNER JOIN T000_WAMI T000
        ON T000.T000F005_WAMI_KEY = T001.T001F010_WAMI_KEY
    INNER JOIN Extracted_Data
        ON Extracted_Data.T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO = T001.T001F005_EMPLOYEE_NO
    INNER JOIN T104_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY T104    
        ON T104.t104f005_employee_no = Extracted_Data.T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO
        AND to_date(N026F025_DATE, 'yyyymmdd')  BETWEEN T104F025_DATE_EFFECTIVE AND T104F030_DATE_TO
ORDER BY
    T001F005_EMPLOYEE_NO
```

**Sample data: two rows, tab delimited with headers**

```
T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO    T526F010_TRANS_NO   T526F900_DATA
```

12345   2913625243271799    ENTRY_LINES=SECTION1=N026F005_SECTION=1N026F015_WEEK_NO=1N026F020_TIME_TYPE=BASICN026F022_ALLOW_TYPE=N026F025_DATE=20220928N026F030_TIME_FROM=0000000009000000N026F035_BREAK_FROM=N026F040_BREAK_TO=N026F045_BREAK_HOURS=0000000001000000N026F050_TIME_TO=0000000017000000N026F055_TIME_HOURS=N026F060_COSTING_CODE_1=N026F065_COSTING_CODE_2=N026F070_COSTING_CODE_3=N026F075_COSTING_CODE_4=N026F080_COSTING_CODE_9=N026F085_ABC_IN_CODE=N026F090_ABC_OUT_CODE=N026F095_AMOUNT=N026F100_HOURS_DAY_1=N026F105_HOURS_DAY_2=N026F110_HOURS_DAY_3=N026F115_HOURS_DAY_4=N026F120_HOURS_DAY_5=N026F125_HOURS_DAY_6=N026F130_HOURS_DAY_7=N026F135_COMMENTS=N026F145_ERROR_MESSAGE=N026F150_CONTRACTOR_HOURS=N026F155_CONTRACTOR_RATE=N026F160_CONTRACTOR_MULT=N026F165_CONTRACTOR_AMOUNT=N026F170_CONTRACTOR_GST=N026F175_CONTRACTOR_TOTAL=N026F180_CUSTOMER_HOURS=N026F185_CUSTOMER_RATE=N026F190_CUSTOMER_MULT=N026F195_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT=N026F200_CUSTOMER_GST=N026F205_CUSTOMER_TOTAL=N026F210_OVERRIDE_CLASS=N026F215_PRIMARY_COST_CODE=N026F220_AMOUNT_DAY_1=N026F225_AMOUNT_DAY_2=N026F230_AMOUNT_DAY_3=N026F235_AMOUNT_DAY_4=N026F240_AMOUNT_DAY_5=N026F245_AMOUNT_DAY_6=N026F250_AMOUNT_DAY_7=N026F255_SHIFT_CODE=DN026F260_LOCATION_CODE=N026F265_DAY_TYPE=MONFRIN026F270_MAJORITY_DAY_TYPE=ANYN026F275_BLOCK_NUMBER=1N026F280_EFF_DATE=N026F285_TEAM_CODE=N026F290_PROCESS_STATUS=1N026F295_DATE_FROM=N026F300_DATE_TO=N026F005_SECTION=1N026F015_WEEK_NO=2N026F020_TIME_TYPE=SHIFTN026F022_ALLOW_TYPE=N026F025_DATE=20221001N026F030_TIME_FROM=0000000013000000N026F035_BREAK_FROM=N026F040_BREAK_TO=N026F045_BREAK_HOURS=0000000000000000N026F050_TIME_TO=0000000017000000N026F055_TIME_HOURS=N026F060_COSTING_CODE_1=N026F065_COSTING_CODE_2=N026F070_COSTING_CODE_3=N026F075_COSTING_CODE_4=N026F080_COSTING_CODE_9=N026F085_ABC_IN_CODE=N026F090_ABC_OUT_CODE=N026F095_AMOUNT=N026F100_HOURS_DAY_1=N026F105_HOURS_DAY_2=N026F110_HOURS_DAY_3=N026F115_HOURS_DAY_4=N026F120_HOURS_DAY_5=N026F125_HOURS_DAY_6=N026F130_HOURS_DAY_7=N026F135_COMMENTS=N026F145_ERROR_MESSAGE=N026F150_CONTRACTOR_HOURS=N026F155_CONTRACTOR_RATE=N026F160_CONTRACTOR_MULT=N026F165_CONTRACTOR_AMOUNT=N026F170_CONTRACTOR_GST=N026F175_CONTRACTOR_TOTAL=N026F180_CUSTOMER_HOURS=N026F185_CUSTOMER_RATE=N026F190_CUSTOMER_MULT=N026F195_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT=N026F200_CUSTOMER_GST=N026F205_CUSTOMER_TOTAL=N026F210_OVERRIDE_CLASS=N026F215_PRIMARY_COST_CODE=N026F220_AMOUNT_DAY_1=N026F225_AMOUNT_DAY_2=N026F230_AMOUNT_DAY_3=N026F235_AMOUNT_DAY_4=N026F240_AMOUNT_DAY_5=N026F245_AMOUNT_DAY_6=N026F250_AMOUNT_DAY_7=N026F255_SHIFT_CODE=DN026F260_LOCATION_CODE=N026F265_DAY_TYPE=SATN026F270_MAJORITY_DAY_TYPE=ANYN026F275_BLOCK_NUMBER=2N026F280_EFF_DATE=N026F285_TEAM_CODE=N026F290_PROCESS_STATUS=1N026F295_DATE_FROM=N026F300_DATE_TO=N026F005_SECTION=1N026F015_WEEK_NO=2N026F020_TIME_TYPE=BASICN026F022_ALLOW_TYPE=N026F025_DATE=20221005N026F030_TIME_FROM=0000000009000000N026F035_BREAK_FROM=N026F040_BREAK_TO=N026F045_BREAK_HOURS=0000000001000000N026F050_TIME_TO=0000000017000000N026F055_TIME_HOURS=N026F060_COSTING_CODE_1=N026F065_COSTING_CODE_2=N026F070_COSTING_CODE_3=N026F075_COSTING_CODE_4=N026F080_COSTING_CODE_9=N026F085_ABC_IN_CODE=N026F090_ABC_OUT_CODE=N026F095_AMOUNT=N026F100_HOURS_DAY_1=N026F105_HOURS_DAY_2=N026F110_HOURS_DAY_3=N026F115_HOURS_DAY_4=N026F120_HOURS_DAY_5=N026F125_HOURS_DAY_6=N026F130_HOURS_DAY_7=N026F135_COMMENTS=N026F145_ERROR_MESSAGE=N026F150_CONTRACTOR_HOURS=N026F155_CONTRACTOR_RATE=N026F160_CONTRACTOR_MULT=N026F165_CONTRACTOR_AMOUNT=N026F170_CONTRACTOR_GST=N026F175_CONTRACTOR_TOTAL=N026F180_CUSTOMER_HOURS=N026F185_CUSTOMER_RATE=N026F190_CUSTOMER_MULT=N026F195_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT=N026F200_CUSTOMER_GST=N026F205_CUSTOMER_TOTAL=N026F210_OVERRIDE_CLASS=N026F215_PRIMARY_COST_CODE=N026F220_AMOUNT_DAY_1=N026F225_AMOUNT_DAY_2=N026F230_AMOUNT_DAY_3=N026F235_AMOUNT_DAY_4=N026F240_AMOUNT_DAY_5=N026F245_AMOUNT_DAY_6=N026F250_AMOUNT_DAY_7=N026F255_SHIFT_CODE=DN026F260_LOCATION_CODE=N026F265_DAY_TYPE=MONFRIN026F270_MAJORITY_DAY_TYPE=ANYN026F275_BLOCK_NUMBER=3N026F280_EFF_DATE=N026F285_TEAM_CODE=N026F290_PROCESS_STATUS=1N026F295_DATE_FROM=N026F300_DATE_TO=SECTION2=SECTION3=SECTION4=SUMMARY_LINES=N027F001_SEQ=N027F005_TYPE=01.01N027F010_HOURS_EXP=14:00N027F015_HOURS_ACT=14:00N027F020_AMOUNT_EXP=N027F025_AMOUNT_ACT=N027F001_SEQ=N027F005_TYPE=01.02N027F010_HOURS_EXP=4:00N027F015_HOURS_ACT=4:00N027F020_AMOUNT_EXP=N027F025_AMOUNT_ACT=T526_FIELDS=T526F500_ERROR_MESSAGE=T526F505_FLEX_1_BF=T526F510_FLEX_1_TAKEN=T526F511_FLEX_1_FORFEIT=T526F512_FLEX_1_XFER=T526F515_FLEX_1_BANKED=T526F520_FLEX_1_CF=T526F525_FLEX_2_BF=T526F530_FLEX_2_TAKEN=T526F531_FLEX_2_FORFEIT=T526F532_FLEX_2_XFER=T526F535_FLEX_2_BANKED=T526F540_FLEX_2_CF=T526F545_CONTRACTOR_HOURS=T526F550_CONTRACTOR_RATE=T526F555_CONTRACTOR_MULT=T526F560_CONTRACTOR_AMOUNT=T526F565_CONTRACTOR_GST=T526F570_CONTRACTOR_FACTOR=T526F575_CONTRACTOR_TOTAL=T526F580_CUSTOMER_HOURS=T526F585_CUSTOMER_RATE=T526F590_CUSTOMER_MULT=T526F595_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT=T526F600_CUSTOMER_GST=T526F605_CUSTOMER_FACTOR=T526F610_CUSTOMER_TOTAL=T526F615_LAST_SELECTION=T526F620_USER_TIMEFRAME=T526F625_RAISED_SOURCE=T526F630_ROSTER_CODE=T526F635_CYCLE_NUMBER=T526F640_USER_OVERRIDDEN=TT526F645_TOTAL_LINES=0SUMMARY_DAY_LINES=SUMMARY_LABEL=01.01SUMMARY_DATE=20220928SUMMARY_MINUTES=420SUMMARY_LABEL=01.02SUMMARY_DATE=20221001SUMMARY_MINUTES=240SUMMARY_LABEL=01.01SUMMARY_DATE=20221005SUMMARY_MINUTES=420SUMMARY_DAY_FLEX_LINES=DAY_TOTALS=N035F005_DAY=N035F010_SHIFT_CODE=N035F015_MINUTES=INCOMPLETE_FLAG=F
12345   2913639243272199    ENTRY_LINES=SECTION1=N026F005_SECTION=1N026F015_WEEK_NO=1N026F020_TIME_TYPE=SHIFTN026F022_ALLOW_TYPE=N026F025_DATE=20220910N026F030_TIME_FROM=0000000013000000N026F035_BREAK_FROM=N026F040_BREAK_TO=N026F045_BREAK_HOURS=0000000000000000N026F050_TIME_TO=0000000017000000N026F055_TIME_HOURS=N026F060_COSTING_CODE_1=N026F065_COSTING_CODE_2=N026F070_COSTING_CODE_3=N026F075_COSTING_CODE_4=N026F080_COSTING_CODE_9=N026F085_ABC_IN_CODE=N026F090_ABC_OUT_CODE=N026F095_AMOUNT=N026F100_HOURS_DAY_1=N026F105_HOURS_DAY_2=N026F110_HOURS_DAY_3=N026F115_HOURS_DAY_4=N026F120_HOURS_DAY_5=N026F125_HOURS_DAY_6=N026F130_HOURS_DAY_7=N026F135_COMMENTS=N026F145_ERROR_MESSAGE=N026F150_CONTRACTOR_HOURS=N026F155_CONTRACTOR_RATE=N026F160_CONTRACTOR_MULT=N026F165_CONTRACTOR_AMOUNT=N026F170_CONTRACTOR_GST=N026F175_CONTRACTOR_TOTAL=N026F180_CUSTOMER_HOURS=N026F185_CUSTOMER_RATE=N026F190_CUSTOMER_MULT=N026F195_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT=N026F200_CUSTOMER_GST=N026F205_CUSTOMER_TOTAL=N026F210_OVERRIDE_CLASS=N026F215_PRIMARY_COST_CODE=N026F220_AMOUNT_DAY_1=N026F225_AMOUNT_DAY_2=N026F230_AMOUNT_DAY_3=N026F235_AMOUNT_DAY_4=N026F240_AMOUNT_DAY_5=N026F245_AMOUNT_DAY_6=N026F250_AMOUNT_DAY_7=N026F255_SHIFT_CODE=DN026F260_LOCATION_CODE=N026F265_DAY_TYPE=SATN026F270_MAJORITY_DAY_TYPE=ANYN026F275_BLOCK_NUMBER=1N026F280_EFF_DATE=N026F285_TEAM_CODE=N026F290_PROCESS_STATUS=1N026F295_DATE_FROM=N026F300_DATE_TO=N026F005_SECTION=1N026F015_WEEK_NO=1N026F020_TIME_TYPE=BASICN026F022_ALLOW_TYPE=N026F025_DATE=20220914N026F030_TIME_FROM=0000000009000000N026F035_BREAK_FROM=N026F040_BREAK_TO=N026F045_BREAK_HOURS=0000000001000000N026F050_TIME_TO=0000000017000000N026F055_TIME_HOURS=N026F060_COSTING_CODE_1=N026F065_COSTING_CODE_2=N026F070_COSTING_CODE_3=N026F075_COSTING_CODE_4=N026F080_COSTING_CODE_9=N026F085_ABC_IN_CODE=N026F090_ABC_OUT_CODE=N026F095_AMOUNT=N026F100_HOURS_DAY_1=N026F105_HOURS_DAY_2=N026F110_HOURS_DAY_3=N026F115_HOURS_DAY_4=N026F120_HOURS_DAY_5=N026F125_HOURS_DAY_6=N026F130_HOURS_DAY_7=N026F135_COMMENTS=N026F145_ERROR_MESSAGE=N026F150_CONTRACTOR_HOURS=N026F155_CONTRACTOR_RATE=N026F160_CONTRACTOR_MULT=N026F165_CONTRACTOR_AMOUNT=N026F170_CONTRACTOR_GST=N026F175_CONTRACTOR_TOTAL=N026F180_CUSTOMER_HOURS=N026F185_CUSTOMER_RATE=N026F190_CUSTOMER_MULT=N026F195_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT=N026F200_CUSTOMER_GST=N026F205_CUSTOMER_TOTAL=N026F210_OVERRIDE_CLASS=N026F215_PRIMARY_COST_CODE=N026F220_AMOUNT_DAY_1=N026F225_AMOUNT_DAY_2=N026F230_AMOUNT_DAY_3=N026F235_AMOUNT_DAY_4=N026F240_AMOUNT_DAY_5=N026F245_AMOUNT_DAY_6=N026F250_AMOUNT_DAY_7=N026F255_SHIFT_CODE=DN026F260_LOCATION_CODE=N026F265_DAY_TYPE=MONFRIN026F270_MAJORITY_DAY_TYPE=ANYN026F275_BLOCK_NUMBER=2N026F280_EFF_DATE=N026F285_TEAM_CODE=N026F290_PROCESS_STATUS=1N026F295_DATE_FROM=N026F300_DATE_TO=N026F005_SECTION=1N026F015_WEEK_NO=2N026F020_TIME_TYPE=BASICN026F022_ALLOW_TYPE=N026F025_DATE=20220921N026F030_TIME_FROM=0000000009000000N026F035_BREAK_FROM=N026F040_BREAK_TO=N026F045_BREAK_HOURS=0000000001000000N026F050_TIME_TO=0000000017000000N026F055_TIME_HOURS=N026F060_COSTING_CODE_1=N026F065_COSTING_CODE_2=N026F070_COSTING_CODE_3=N026F075_COSTING_CODE_4=N026F080_COSTING_CODE_9=N026F085_ABC_IN_CODE=N026F090_ABC_OUT_CODE=N026F095_AMOUNT=N026F100_HOURS_DAY_1=N026F105_HOURS_DAY_2=N026F110_HOURS_DAY_3=N026F115_HOURS_DAY_4=N026F120_HOURS_DAY_5=N026F125_HOURS_DAY_6=N026F130_HOURS_DAY_7=N026F135_COMMENTS=N026F145_ERROR_MESSAGE=N026F150_CONTRACTOR_HOURS=N026F155_CONTRACTOR_RATE=N026F160_CONTRACTOR_MULT=N026F165_CONTRACTOR_AMOUNT=N026F170_CONTRACTOR_GST=N026F175_CONTRACTOR_TOTAL=N026F180_CUSTOMER_HOURS=N026F185_CUSTOMER_RATE=N026F190_CUSTOMER_MULT=N026F195_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT=N026F200_CUSTOMER_GST=N026F205_CUSTOMER_TOTAL=N026F210_OVERRIDE_CLASS=N026F215_PRIMARY_COST_CODE=N026F220_AMOUNT_DAY_1=N026F225_AMOUNT_DAY_2=N026F230_AMOUNT_DAY_3=N026F235_AMOUNT_DAY_4=N026F240_AMOUNT_DAY_5=N026F245_AMOUNT_DAY_6=N026F250_AMOUNT_DAY_7=N026F255_SHIFT_CODE=DN026F260_LOCATION_CODE=N026F265_DAY_TYPE=MONFRIN026F270_MAJORITY_DAY_TYPE=ANYN026F275_BLOCK_NUMBER=3N026F280_EFF_DATE=N026F285_TEAM_CODE=N026F290_PROCESS_STATUS=1N026F295_DATE_FROM=N026F300_DATE_TO=N026F005_SECTION=1N026F015_WEEK_NO=2N026F020_TIME_TYPE=SHIFTN026F022_ALLOW_TYPE=N026F025_DATE=20220922N026F030_TIME_FROM=0000000013000000N026F035_BREAK_FROM=N026F040_BREAK_TO=N026F045_BREAK_HOURS=0000000000000000N026F050_TIME_TO=0000000017000000N026F055_TIME_HOURS=N026F060_COSTING_CODE_1=N026F065_COSTING_CODE_2=N026F070_COSTING_CODE_3=N026F075_COSTING_CODE_4=N026F080_COSTING_CODE_9=N026F085_ABC_IN_CODE=N026F090_ABC_OUT_CODE=N026F095_AMOUNT=N026F100_HOURS_DAY_1=N026F105_HOURS_DAY_2=N026F110_HOURS_DAY_3=N026F115_HOURS_DAY_4=N026F120_HOURS_DAY_5=N026F125_HOURS_DAY_6=N026F130_HOURS_DAY_7=N026F135_COMMENTS=N026F145_ERROR_MESSAGE=N026F150_CONTRACTOR_HOURS=N026F155_CONTRACTOR_RATE=N026F160_CONTRACTOR_MULT=N026F165_CONTRACTOR_AMOUNT=N026F170_CONTRACTOR_GST=N026F175_CONTRACTOR_TOTAL=N026F180_CUSTOMER_HOURS=N026F185_CUSTOMER_RATE=N026F190_CUSTOMER_MULT=N026F195_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT=N026F200_CUSTOMER_GST=N026F205_CUSTOMER_TOTAL=N026F210_OVERRIDE_CLASS=N026F215_PRIMARY_COST_CODE=N026F220_AMOUNT_DAY_1=N026F225_AMOUNT_DAY_2=N026F230_AMOUNT_DAY_3=N026F235_AMOUNT_DAY_4=N026F240_AMOUNT_DAY_5=N026F245_AMOUNT_DAY_6=N026F250_AMOUNT_DAY_7=N026F255_SHIFT_CODE=DN026F260_LOCATION_CODE=N026F265_DAY_TYPE=PUBHOLN026F270_MAJORITY_DAY_TYPE=ANYN026F275_BLOCK_NUMBER=4N026F280_EFF_DATE=N026F285_TEAM_CODE=N026F290_PROCESS_STATUS=1N026F295_DATE_FROM=N026F300_DATE_TO=SECTION2=SECTION3=SECTION4=SUMMARY_LINES=N027F001_SEQ=N027F005_TYPE=01.02N027F010_HOURS_EXP=8:00N027F015_HOURS_ACT=8:00N027F020_AMOUNT_EXP=N027F025_AMOUNT_ACT=N027F001_SEQ=N027F005_TYPE=01.01N027F010_HOURS_EXP=14:00N027F015_HOURS_ACT=14:00N027F020_AMOUNT_EXP=N027F025_AMOUNT_ACT=T526_FIELDS=T526F500_ERROR_MESSAGE=T526F505_FLEX_1_BF=T526F510_FLEX_1_TAKEN=T526F511_FLEX_1_FORFEIT=T526F512_FLEX_1_XFER=T526F515_FLEX_1_BANKED=T526F520_FLEX_1_CF=T526F525_FLEX_2_BF=T526F530_FLEX_2_TAKEN=T526F531_FLEX_2_FORFEIT=T526F532_FLEX_2_XFER=T526F535_FLEX_2_BANKED=T526F540_FLEX_2_CF=T526F545_CONTRACTOR_HOURS=T526F550_CONTRACTOR_RATE=T526F555_CONTRACTOR_MULT=T526F560_CONTRACTOR_AMOUNT=T526F565_CONTRACTOR_GST=T526F570_CONTRACTOR_FACTOR=T526F575_CONTRACTOR_TOTAL=T526F580_CUSTOMER_HOURS=T526F585_CUSTOMER_RATE=T526F590_CUSTOMER_MULT=T526F595_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT=T526F600_CUSTOMER_GST=T526F605_CUSTOMER_FACTOR=T526F610_CUSTOMER_TOTAL=T526F615_LAST_SELECTION=T526F620_USER_TIMEFRAME=T526F625_RAISED_SOURCE=T526F630_ROSTER_CODE=T526F635_CYCLE_NUMBER=T526F640_USER_OVERRIDDEN=TT526F645_TOTAL_LINES=0SUMMARY_DAY_LINES=SUMMARY_LABEL=01.02SUMMARY_DATE=20220910SUMMARY_MINUTES=240SUMMARY_LABEL=01.01SUMMARY_DATE=20220914SUMMARY_MINUTES=420SUMMARY_LABEL=01.01SUMMARY_DATE=20220921SUMMARY_MINUTES=420SUMMARY_LABEL=01.02SUMMARY_DATE=20220922SUMMARY_MINUTES=240SUMMARY_DAY_FLEX_LINES=DAY_TOTALS=N035F005_DAY=N035F010_SHIFT_CODE=N035F015_MINUTES=INCOMPLETE_FLAG=F

Comment: It is **MUCH** harder to answer a question if you have to reverse engineer the input data from a description and from some code. What you should do is to provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data that people can copy/paste.

Comment: Having the delimiter between lines as the characters `21,21,27` and the delimiter between terms on a line of `21,21,21,27` makes it difficult to search for ends of lines as you will match the last 3 characters of the end of each term delimiter. You should probably consider using different delimiters that do not overlap.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple string functions (as they are much faster than regular expressions) and, assuming that each line has a fixed number of terms, you can parse the terms at the same time as the lines using a recursive sub-query factoring clause.

Assuming the terms are in a fixed order on each line:

```sql
WITH bounds (EMPLOYEE_NO, TRANS_NO, DATA, spos, tpos1, tpos2, tpos3, epos) AS (
  SELECT T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO,
         T526F010_TRANS_NO,
         T526F900_DATA,
         1,
         INSTR(T526F900_DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), 1, 1),
         INSTR(T526F900_DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), 1, 2),
         INSTR(T526F900_DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), 1, 3),
         INSTR(
           T526F900_DATA,
           CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27),
           INSTR(T526F900_DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), 1, 3) + 4 
         )
  FROM   T526_TIME_ENTRY_HEADER
UNION ALL
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_NO,
         TRANS_NO,
         DATA,
         epos + 3,
         INSTR(DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), epos + 1, 1),
         INSTR(DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), epos + 1, 2),
         INSTR(DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), epos + 1, 3),
         INSTR(
           DATA,
           CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27),
           INSTR(DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), epos + 1, 3) + 4 
         )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos  > 0
),
terms (employee_no, trans_no, term1, term2, term3, term4) AS (
  SELECT employee_no,
         trans_no,
         SUBSTR(data, spos,      tpos1 - spos),
         SUBSTR(data, tpos1 + 4, tpos2 - tpos1 - 4),
         SUBSTR(data, tpos2 + 4, tpos3 - tpos2 - 4),
         CASE epos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(data, tpos3 + 4)
         ELSE SUBSTR(data, tpos3 + 4, epos  - tpos3 - 4)
         END
  FROM   bounds
)
SELECT employee_no,
       trans_no,
       SUBSTR(term1, 16, 10) AS N026F025_DATE,
       SUBSTR(term2, 21, 8) AS N026F025_TIME_FROM,
       SUBSTR(term3, 19, 8) AS N026F025_TIME_TO,
       RTRIM(SUBSTR(term4, 21), '.') AS N026F025_TIME_TYPE
FROM   terms
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T526_TIME_ENTRY_HEADER(
  T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO NUMBER,
  T526F010_TRANS_NO NUMBER,
  T526F900_DATA BLOB
);

INSERT INTO T526_TIME_ENTRY_HEADER (T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO, T526F010_TRANS_NO, T526F900_DATA)
VALUES (
  1,
  1.1,
  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(
    'N026F025_DATE=.2022-01-01.' || CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27) ||
    'N026F030_TIME_FROM=.06:00:00.' || CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27) ||
    'N026F050_TIME_TO=.11:00:00.' || CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27) ||
    'N026F020_TIME_TYPE=.XYZ.' || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27) ||
    'N026F025_DATE=.2022-01-01.' || CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27) ||
    'N026F030_TIME_FROM=.12:00:00.' || CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27) ||
    'N026F050_TIME_TO=.19:00:00.' || CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27) ||
    'N026F020_TIME_TYPE=.ABC.'
  )
);
```

Outputs:

| EMPLOYEE_NO | TRANS_NO | N026F025_DATE | N026F025_TIME_FROM | N026F025_TIME_TO | N026F025_TIME_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | 2022-01-01 | 06:00:00 | 11:00:00 | XYZ |
| 1 | 1.1 | 2022-01-01 | 12:00:00 | 19:00:00 | ABC |

---

If the terms in a line can be in any order then:

```
WITH bounds (EMPLOYEE_NO, TRANS_NO, DATA, spos, tpos1, tpos2, tpos3, epos) AS (
  SELECT T526F005_EMPLOYEE_NO,
         T526F010_TRANS_NO,
         T526F900_DATA,
         1,
         INSTR(T526F900_DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), 1, 1),
         INSTR(T526F900_DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), 1, 2),
         INSTR(T526F900_DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), 1, 3),
         INSTR(
           T526F900_DATA,
           CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27),
           INSTR(T526F900_DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), 1, 3) + 4 
         )
  FROM   T526_TIME_ENTRY_HEADER
UNION ALL
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_NO,
         TRANS_NO,
         DATA,
         epos + 3,
         INSTR(DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), epos + 1, 1),
         INSTR(DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), epos + 1, 2),
         INSTR(DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), epos + 1, 3),
         INSTR(
           DATA,
           CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27),
           INSTR(DATA, CHR(21) || CHR(21) || CHR (21) || CHR(27), epos + 1, 3) + 4 
         )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos  > 0
),
terms (employee_no, trans_no, term1, term2, term3, term4) AS (
  SELECT employee_no,
         trans_no,
         SUBSTR(data, spos,      tpos1 - spos),
         SUBSTR(data, tpos1 + 4, tpos2 - tpos1 - 4),
         SUBSTR(data, tpos2 + 4, tpos3 - tpos2 - 4),
         CASE epos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(data, tpos3 + 4)
         ELSE SUBSTR(data, tpos3 + 4, epos  - tpos3 - 4)
         END
  FROM   bounds
)
SELECT employee_no,
       trans_no,
       CASE
       WHEN term1 LIKE 'N026F025_DATE=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term1, 16, 10)
       WHEN term2 LIKE 'N026F025_DATE=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term2, 16, 10)
       WHEN term3 LIKE 'N026F025_DATE=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term3, 16, 10)
       WHEN term4 LIKE 'N026F025_DATE=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term4, 16, 10)
       END AS N026F025_DATE,
       CASE
       WHEN term1 LIKE 'N026F030_TIME_FROM=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term1, 21, 8)
       WHEN term2 LIKE 'N026F030_TIME_FROM=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term2, 21, 8)
       WHEN term3 LIKE 'N026F030_TIME_FROM=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term3, 21, 8)
       WHEN term4 LIKE 'N026F030_TIME_FROM=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term4, 21, 8)
       END AS N026F025_TIME_FROM,
       CASE
       WHEN term1 LIKE 'N026F050_TIME_TO=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term1, 19, 8)
       WHEN term2 LIKE 'N026F050_TIME_TO=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term2, 19, 8)
       WHEN term3 LIKE 'N026F050_TIME_TO=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term3, 19, 8)
       WHEN term4 LIKE 'N026F050_TIME_TO=.%'
       THEN SUBSTR(term4, 19, 8)
       END AS N026F025_TIME_TO,
       CASE
       WHEN term1 LIKE 'N026F020_TIME_TYPE=.%'
       THEN RTRIM(SUBSTR(term1, 21), '.')
       WHEN term2 LIKE 'N026F020_TIME_TYPE=.%'
       THEN RTRIM(SUBSTR(term2, 21), '.')
       WHEN term3 LIKE 'N026F020_TIME_TYPE=.%'
       THEN RTRIM(SUBSTR(term3, 21), '.')
       WHEN term4 LIKE 'N026F020_TIME_TYPE=.%'
       THEN RTRIM(SUBSTR(term4, 21), '.')
       END AS N026F025_TIME_TYPE
FROM   terms
```

Which outputs the same for the sample data.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y0qRu3vB)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide such a comprehensive and generous answer! The delimiters are a default in the off-the-shelf application and not in my control to change unfortunately, but it's very helpful to know that regexp expressions are slower than simpler string functions. I'll try implementing your solution and come back to confirm.  If not, I'll also redact a sample of data and share it here (HR data so can't share raw data)